# How to clip text overflow bootstrap dropdown button

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown button similar to this [dropdown button](http://jsfiddle.net/cmcculloh/xnpf1rr9/).  When text is very long, the caret and the text overflows the button entire width or when resize window to very small width screen. How to clip the text only. And the caret stays.  I have tried using these on the button element.

```
text-overflow:clip; 
white-space:nowrap; 
overflow:hidden;
```

The problem is when it clips, the caret disappears. I want that caret stays when text clipping chosen list from drowndown which is very long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `caret` and `text` is inside the `button`...

So just wrap the `dropdown` text into a `span` and apply `white-space` property to that `span` instead of `button`...

And to `white-space` to work you have to define a `max-width` property too.

Also changed your `jQuery` code to change the text...

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/k5c2ecmn/1/)**

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn span.text').text($(this).data('value'));
});
```

```css
.btn-default.dropdown-toggle .text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="text">Dropdown Dropdown Dropdown</span>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-value="separated link">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I did that already, but my problem is the list. When text is very long, the list text overflows the button.

Comment: @anni you want to clip the dropdown list content till the button width?/

Comment: Yes, the button width is 100%. It accomodates pretty well long text. Problem is in the responsive side. When screen width is pretty narrow. It does not accomodate long text.

Comment: here is a new fork on jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/9tu9w4hs/. actually the button and the ul li are wrapped inside a div  class name container the width is  300px .  css here .container{
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.btn{
  position:relative;
  top:1px;
  max-width:100%;
  
} if you notice if text is very long, it goes beyond the button and the wrapper container. tha tis the reason i want to clip the text but the caret stays.

Comment: thanks, i will study your suggestion and see how can i apply it.

Answer (score 0):

```
white-space:nowrap; overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:hidden;
```

try this

Comment: This gives a scrollbar to button. Is that the requirement ?

Comment: No, as much as possible only clipping of text

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your button has following styles:

```
.btn{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can give this style to caret.

```
.caret{
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

Here is a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/rachit5/8vLjyu2x/1

Comment: Yes, it clips but not text chosen from the list.

Comment: Check the example.

Comment: Not sure what you'r looking for if that example did not work for you.